# What is the purpose to define the variance of the Bernoulli trial?

Tags: probability

What is the purpose to define the variance of the Bernoulli trial while we have the probability of each success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good reason is as follows. Let $Y$ be the number of successes in $n$ independent trials, where the probability of success each time is $p$. Let $X_i=1$ if we have a success on the $i$-th trial, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise.
Then 
$$Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n.$$
By independence,
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X_i).$$
We know that the variance of each $X_i$ is $p(1-p)$, and therefore $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=np(1-p)$.

Knowing the variance of a binomial is quite useful, and this is a simple way of computing it.

Comment: Why it is useful to compute variance of the trial?

Comment: I should have mentioned that there are similar more complicated computations. As to why knowing the variance of a binomial is useful, it is necessary if we are going to make a normal approximation.

Comment: What is a normal approximation?

Comment: Normal approximation is too lengthy to discuss in a comment. But "normal approximation to the binomial" should yield many hits. As to why not divide $np(1-p)$ by $2$, the mean of the binomial is $np$.